# Как уменьшить количество if в коде?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, if

Суть кода в том чтобы он высчитывал количество соседей у клетки по координатам.

Есть список с координатами живых клеток, код смотрит есть ли у данной клетки живые соседи.

```
public Integer getNeighbourCount(int x, int y) {

        int counter = 0;

        for (ArrayList<Integer> coordinate : coordinates) {
            if (coordinate.get(0) == x && coordinate.get(1) == y + 1) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x + 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x && coordinate.get(1) == y - 1) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x - 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x + 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y + 1) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x - 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y - 1) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x - 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y + 1) {
                counter++;
            } else if (coordinate.get(0) == x + 1 && coordinate.get(1) == y - 1) {
                counter++;
            }

        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Нужно уменьшить количество if.

Comment: циклы + тернарные операторы

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
public Integer getNeighbourCount(int x, int y) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (ArrayList<Integer> coordinate : coordinates) {            
        int cx = coordinate.get(0);
        int cy = coordinate.get(1);
        
        if (cx == x && cy == y) continue;
        if (Math.abs(cx - x) <= 1 && Math.abs(cy - y) <= 1) counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
int cx = coordinate.get(0);
int cy = coordinate.get(1);
if (cx >= x-1 && cx <= x+1 && cy >= y-1 && cy <= y+1) {
     counter++;
}
```

Comment: варианта, что координаты у автора равны x и y нет. А у вас есть. То есть код не совсем эквивалентен.